how to decode sbus in UART?
I need to read the sbus signal coming from my receiver mc7rb-v2 using Raspberry Pi 5, I have made a signal inverter as stated in the manual of the receiver and connected to uart pin, I use pyserial to receive data from UART but I don't know how to decode this data
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
    baudrate = 100000,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
)

while True:
     x=ser.read(25)
     print(x)

output:
b'\x0e\xc0\x02\x1e\x80\x80\x06<\xe0\x00\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

output

You might be able to get better answers at [raspberrypi.se].
